# Error al eliminar las filas que tengan NaN en una columna de un dataframe

Tags: pandas

Con importaciones de ficheros .csv, he creado el siguiente df.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intento eliminar las filas con NaN en la columna "Iberdrola, utilizando el bucle.

> if symbol == 'Iberdrola':
>               df = df.dropna(subset ='Iberdrola')

Al ejecutar me devuleve el error

> TypeError: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind,
>   'Iberdrola' was passed

¿Cómo podría subsanar este error?

Comment: El parámetro pasado a través de `subset` debe ser iterable, es decir, una lista o una tupla. Pon `subset=['Iberdrola']` .

Comment: Efectivamente cambiando a

Comment: Efectivamente cambiando a df = df.dropna(subset = ['Iberdrola']) funcina correctamente. Gracias